# Text box with long text get two rows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, drag-and-drop

Im using drag and drop from list box to text box and the problem when the item(string) is too long and i drag it to text box I see just the end of the text which was dragged and I see
it in 2 rows ,how can I change it that when the long text is dragged to see the 
start of it if its bigger than the text box.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In textboxes `drag` event paste this code to the end of event ;

```
textBox1.Focus();
textBox1.SelectAll();
SendKeys.Send("{LEFT}");
```

This will put the bracket to start of textBox's text

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This may help you.

```
    bool isTextDropped = false;

    void textBox_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string tstring;
        tstring = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat).ToString();
        textBox.Text += " " + tstring;
        isTextDropped = true;  
    }       

    void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isTextDropped)
        {
            textBox.SelectionStart = 0;
            textBox.SelectionLength = 0;
            isTextDropped = false;
        }
    }
```